# Remove Fancybox Magento Add to Cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, fancybox

I got a problem with Magento add to cart button on product pages, when add to cart buttons clicked, it shows a popup with checkout button but I don't want that popup else I want to redirect the add-to-cart button to the checkout page when clicked. I commented every fancybox code in the website but no help. Can you help me out in this?

my test website is: usecureme.mythstreet.com

Comment: Post your add to cart button code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple. It's basically AjaxCart module that resides under your Magento folders. To locate and disable the ajaxcart, go to:

app/etc/modules/Ajaxcart.xml

Open it, there will be a code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ajaxcart>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Ajaxcart>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Put 'false' instead of that true.

```
                <active>false</active>
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

You can check some javascript codes in your product page.

```
productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;
                if (url) {
                    form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                if ( $(button).id.indexOf('ec_shortcut') != -1  ) {
                    try {
                        this.form.submit();
                        return;
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                }
                if (!url) {
                    url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
                }
                url = url.replace("checkout/cart","oxajax/cart");
                url = url.replace("wishlist/index/cart", "oxajax/cart/add");
                var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
                data += '&isAjax=1';
                if ('https:' == document.location.protocol) {
                    url = url.replace('http:', 'https:');
                }
                jQuery.fancybox.showActivity();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    dataType:'jsonp',
                    type:'post',
                    data:data,
                    success:function (data) {
                        Olegnax.Ajaxcart.helpers.showMessage(data.message);
                        Olegnax.Ajaxcart.helpers.cartSuccessFunc(data);
                    }
                });
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

In this javascript code, change the following code :

```
Olegnax.Ajaxcart.helpers.showMessage(data.message);
Olegnax.Ajaxcart.helpers.cartSuccessFunc(data);
```

To:

```
location.href = '/checkout'; or ( location.href="/onepage" )
```

And also remove this line jQuery.fancybox.showActivity();

In other words, remove two lines and add a new one ( location.href='/checkout'; )

Then, it will redirect to the checkout page as soon as adding to the cart.

Comment: Your answer may be valid but I failed to locate the code but I found another solution, read below.

Comment: Yeah. You can disable the ajax cart module, but it doesn't redirect to the checkout page when adding to the cart. You should update that javascript although the ajaxcart module was disabled.

Comment: No, I didn't need to do it. I just deactivated it and then under configuration setting, I make it to redirect to "checkout" page after "add to cart". Then I get into the cart controller files and made the link change from "checkout" to "onepage" checkout that's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 1 go to Systems -> ADVANCED -> Advanced and look for "Ajaxcart" module in the "Disable Modules Output" section. Disable the module. Clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2, Navigate to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart. Look for "After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart".